# Why am I getting nan as output for the code below?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a calculator for finding the roots of an equation. I used string to get the numbers and then converted the strings with `stringstream` to their numerical types for the calculation;

because I wanted to make a loop so that a user can use the calculator as long as they want until they quit in any part of entering the `a`,`b`,`c` values.

When I write `a=1`, `b=2`, `c=1`, I get nan for `x1` and `x2`.

I checked `isnan(d)` and `isnan(-b/2*a)` separately but they are not nan. And they are not `0/0` either. Why am I getting nan, does that has to do with the way I used strings?

```cpp
    #include<iostream>
    #include<sstream>
    #include<string>
    #include<cmath>

    using namespace std;

    void root_calculator(string stra="", string strb="", string strc="")
    {
        int a=0,b=0,c=0;
        float d=0.0,x1=0.0,x2=0.0,real=0.0,im=0.0;

        d = (b*b) - (4*a*c);

            if (d >= 0)
            {
                x1= (-b + (sqrt(d)))/(2*a);
                x2= (-b - (sqrt(d)))/(2*a);
                cout << "x1= "<< x1 << " x2= " << x2 << endl;
            }
                else{
                    cout << "Roots are imaginary";
                    real = -b / (2*a);
                    im = (sqrt (-d)) / (2*a);
                    cout << "x1= " << real << "+" << im << endl;
                    cout << "x1= " << real << "-" << im << endl;
                }

    }

    int main()
    {
        int a=0,b=0,c=0;
        string stra,strb,strc;

        cout << "enter a,b,c \n>>a=";
        getline(cin,stra);
        stringstream(stra) >> a;
        cout << "\n>>b=";
        getline(cin,strb);
        stringstream(strb) >> b;
        cout << "\n>>c=";
        getline(cin,strc);
        stringstream(strc) >> c;

        while (stra!= "quit" && strb!= "quit" && strc!="quit")
        {
            root_calculator(stra,strb,strc);

            cout << ">>a=";
            getline(cin,stra);
            stringstream(stra)>>a;
            cout << "\n>>b=";
            getline(cin,strb);
            stringstream(strb)>>b;
            cout << "\n>>c=";
            getline(cin,strc);
            stringstream(strc)>>c;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Hint: You never use values provided by user anywhere.

Comment: Why are you passing strings to `root_calculator` instead of `a`, `b`, and `c`? Also, the variables of the same names inside `root_calculator` are completely unrelated to the ones in `main`.

Comment: What do you mean you "get none"? No code here prints "none".

Comment: sorry I made a typo, it should have been nan, not none.

Comment: To explain the NaN: `a` is zero, so `2 * a` is zero, so you're dividing by zero.

Comment: but `a` is zero just for the initializing, isn't it changing when the user enters the `a` input?

Comment: Those are different variables that happen to have the same name. You should pass `a`, `b`, and `c` as arguments from `main`.

Comment: ah got it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code fails here:

```
x1= (-b + (sqrt(d)))/(2*a);
x2= (-b - (sqrt(d)))/(2*a);
```

because of this:

```
void root_calculator(string stra="", string strb="", string strc="")
{
    int a=0,b=0,c=0;
```

especially because the parameters stra, strb and strc are never used...
so you end up dividing by zero....

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, youre dividing by 0 and never appending the user submitted values to their respective variable. To be more precise, you dont do this:

```
int a = stra;
int b = strb;
int c = strc;
```

But you cant put string values into integer variables. You should then either read the values as int with something like:

```
cin >> a
```

or parse the string into an int.